# What is the genre of "why not me?"- Carrie the musical?

Tags: genre

What is the genre of the song "Why not me? - Carrie the musical? I've already looked through many pages but can't seem to find it.

Comment: It is a song from a piece of musical theater. What more do you need to know? You have already correctly identified the source of the song, and its composers and performers. Why do you need to know what "genre" it is?

Comment: All the information is here. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrie_(musical)

Comment: Its style could be described as "Broadway musical" or "West End musical" or "musical theater" of course. Is this not obvious from the name "Carrie, The Musical"?

Answer (score 1):

This is a Broadway theater song, not a radio hit, but it's probably closest to the "[Adult Contemporary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adult_contemporary_music)" genre.

As has been mentioned elsewhere here, genre is often primarily based on marketing categories.  This song would definitely be marketed primarily to theater fans --you might hear it on a "Theater Songs" internet channel.